# Using the rule stated below, is there a way I can plant trees on a 2D plane such that there are no trees in the first k diagonals?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, cellular-automata

This question was part of the problem set for PROMYS Europe 2020, a maths (or math, just in case I made anyone unhappy) camp held at Oxford every year. It was the one which I couldn't do, and I am still puzzled by it to this day:

The Mathematical Forest is grown in a two-dimensional plane, where trees can only grow on
points with integer coordinates. To start with, there are no trees at all. The foresters plant
the first tree at (0, 0). Each year, they carry out tree planting according to the following
rule. If there is a tree on the point (m, n) but there are no trees on the points (m + 1, n) and
(m, n + 1), then they can choose to remove the tree on (m, n) and plant new trees on the
points (m, n + 1) and (m + 1, n).

For an integer k ≥ 1, the kth diagonal consists of all points (m, n) with m + n = k − 1. Is
it possible for the foresters to arrange their planting so that eventually there are no trees on
the first 2 diagonals? What about the first 3 diagonals? 4 diagonals? Can you generalize?

P.S. The deadline has already passed, so please do not think that I am cheating! The camp was actually cancelled due to obvious reasons, which sucks, because I really looked forward to going.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Noted. I'll edit the post ASAP

Comment: A relevant tag would be [tag:cellular-automata], I suppose, but [tag:trees] is for something else entirely.

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully I'll be able to familiarise myself with all mathematical jargon soon.

Comment: You're welcome :)